# I can get Internet Access, Though I cannot Use Instant Messagings (LINE, Zalo, Viber)

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, installation, internet, android-emulator

I have a problem regarding the internet connection to my android applications, e.g. Instagram, LINE, Viber, etc.

I use Android x-86 version 5.1 (Lollipop) on Vm-ware.

Actually, I have internet connectivity, I can access internet via web browser. Though I cannot use my android application that I mentioned above.

How to solve that problem. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.